# How can I redirect port 80 to a different location through htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, location

I'm on shared hosting and don't have access to virtualhosts to define separate ones for port 443 vs 80.

Is there some straightforward way of defining a separate DocumentRoot or location based on the port in htaccess?

I want to have a CMS (Wordpress) running on **https** and the "temporary" site as http which is only 2 files: index.html and a contact.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you index.html and contact.html is in the document root of your entire site, you could try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(|index\.html|contact\.html)$ /temporary/$1 [L]
```

"temporary" is the folder that your index.html and contact.html files are in.